# Display String having html code in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

This is my string:-

```
String valueofString ="<p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Sheraton Seattle Hotel, you'll be centrally located in Seattle, steps from 5th Avenue Theater and Washington State Convention Center. This 4-star" ;
```

Now I need to display this string in html but html  elements is printing as it is by jsp output .

I tried like this:

```
<c:out value="${valueofString}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

but it is not work for me.

any help would be appreciated .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you wrote *I tired like this:* but forgot to add codes

Comment: What does "by printing as it is" mean? Do you want e.g. that `<br/>` is displayed as `<br/>` (=escaped) or do you want a line break?

Comment: I don't want to print <br/> , instead of it I want line break like same as paragraph tag (<p>).

Answer (score 1):

Add `<textarea>` `</textarea>` to the begining and at the end of your string.

```
String valueofString ="<textarea><p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at Sheraton Seattle Hotel, you'll be centrally located in Seattle, steps from 5th Avenue Theater and Washington State Convention Center. This 4-star</textarea>" ;
```

Comment: I tried with this suggestion but still it not working .And I surprised the <textarea> is working but inside this  again I am getting html tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but you can use scriplet to do this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm

```
<% 
    String valueofString ="<p><b>Property Location</b> <br />With a stay at ...";
    out.write(valueofString); 
%>
```

Something like this should be better:

Java:

```
String location ="Property Location";
String detail ="With a stay at ...";
```

JSP:

```
<p>
    <b><c:out value="${location}" /></b><br/>
    <c:out value="${detail}" />
</p>
```